# airflow: XCom UI error: TypeError: Object of type 'datetime' is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, docker, flask, airflow

I get the error in Airflow UI, when try to get XComs page (Admin -> XComs) http://localhost:18888/admin/xcom/

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Node: 0950da627806
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2311, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1834, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1737, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 36, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1832, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1818, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_admin/base.py", line 69, in inner
    return self._run_view(f, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_admin/base.py", line 368, in _run_view
    return fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_admin/model/base.py", line 2056, in index_view
    return_url=self._get_list_url(view_args),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_admin/base.py", line 308, in render
    return render_template(template, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 135, in render_template
    context, ctx.app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 117, in _render
    rv = template.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/asyncsupport.py", line 76, in render
    return original_render(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1008, in render
    return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 780, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/_compat.py", line 37, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/src/apache-airflow/airflow/www/templates/airflow/model_list.html", line 18, in top-level template code
    {% extends 'admin/model/list.html' %}
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_admin/templates/bootstrap3/admin/model/list.html", line 6, in top-level template code
    {% import 'admin/model/row_actions.html' as row_actions with context %}
  File "/src/apache-airflow/airflow/www/templates/admin/master.html", line 18, in top-level template code
    {% extends 'admin/base.html' %}
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_admin/templates/bootstrap3/admin/base.html", line 38, in top-level template code
    {% block page_body %}
...
...
TypeError: Object of type 'datetime' is not JSON serializable
```

All dags work right and this error occurs only in XComs tab.
I run airflow in docker, does anybody meet this error?

Comment: I'm also getting this since upgrading to 1.10.12 - did you solve it?